# How to group an array in the fastest way?

Tags: ruby

I am grouping array items using the below code but it feels slow.
Is there a faster/better way to group?

```
@tasks_sorted = @tasks.group_by(&:start_date).map  do |month, data|

      hash = {"date" => month}

      data.each {|placement| hash["tasks"] = data}

      hash

    end
```

Comment: The code is misleading the logic.. Not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think below you are looking for :

```
@tasks_sorted = @tasks.group_by(&:start_date).map  do |month, data| 
   {"date" => month, "tasks" => data }
end
```

Comment: The OP's intention is not clear, but this code is at least equivalent to the OP's. I hope it does not get ignored again.

Comment: Thanks again guys and again I am not ignoring anyone ;)